# MongoDB Sharding

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to mongodb.
I want to create a Shard Cluster with single Replica Set,In future, if I want to want to extend it will be easy.

Now, Have 4 Ubuntu machine, 1 will work as Router(mongos) and remaining 3 as used as replica set(Primary,Secondary,Secondary).

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /mnt/md0/data/mongodb/dbdata/
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:

#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /mnt/md0/data/mongodb/logs/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

#processManagement:

security:
  keyFile: /opt/mongo/mongo-keyfile

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: rs0

sharding:
  clusterRole: configsvr

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:**strong text**


#mongos.conf

 # where to write logging data.

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongos.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  #bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.10.10.10

security:
  keyFile: /opt/mongo/mongo-keyfile

sharding:
  configDB: rs0/Primary_Rs:27017,Secondary1_Rs:27017,Secondary2_Rs:27017
```

When I am trying to add the Shard in mongos console, I am getting [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM2HV.png)

Please help me to resolve me the issue.
Thank you In Advance

Answer (score 0):

See you have 2 sharding part in your conf file... and first one config clusterRole as configsvr  => remove/comment this one, and retry

Comment: Thank You for your response,
I have removed the Configsvr section for mongod.conf file.Now, I am not able to login to the mongos console, It is throwing error say connection refused.